# split a rectangle with triangles into polygons as uniformly as possible

Tags: geometry, triangles, computational-geometry, polygons, triangulation

Given a rectangle $A$ and $n$ triangles $\{B_1,B_2,...,B_n\}$, 
I put the triangles inside $A$, at least one vertex of each triangle is not outside $A$ (inside $A$ or on the edge of $A$). So that A is split into $m$ polygons $\{C_1,C_2,...,C_m\}$ without overlapping.

How should I put $\{B_1,B_2,...,B_n\}$ in order to maximum $m$?

How should I put $\{B_1,B_2,...,B_n\}$ in order to minimize the variance of the areas of polygons $\{C_1,C_2,...,C_m\}$? namely to split the rectangle into polygons as uniformly as possible?

Comment: Is there some obvious reason you don't seek the minimum $m$ for the fixed number $n$ of triangles? Also you may want to require at least one vertex of each of the $n$ triangles to be interior to the rectangle, otherwise some of the triangles meet the rectangle in isolated points of its boundary (or maybe that case is still interesting...).

Comment: Are you assuming that a polygon $C_i$ can have its boundary formed from several $B_j$ and from the boundary of $A$? If so, this is horrendously difficult. Even figuring out the maximum number of polygons can be formed by three overlapping triangles is difficult! Or are you saying that the *triangles* do not overlap?

Comment: @almagest Yes, $C_i$ has its boundary formed by some $B_j$ and the boundary of $A$. This is exactly what I want. The triangles can overlap..Hoping someone can give some idea..

Comment: @coffeemath I want to seek the maximum $m$ due to my application. It's similar to a fence system. each fence's coverage is simplified to a triangle. I want the triangle-shape fences to split the plane into polygons as many and uniformly as possible.  So that if I know which fences are triggered, I can get a rough estimation of target's position. And the case that some triangles meet the rectangle in isolated points of its boundary may be equivalent to decrease $n$. I guess larger $n$ should have larger $m$, so such case should not be in the correct result.